# Variable not defined error in image control variable in vba

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

```
hIcon = Sheet1.Image1.Picture.Handle
```

I have sheet1 with image control with the name **image1** but still getting this issue?
Please help me with this. where I am doing wrong?

Comment: According to your image hIcon is not declared. You need to declare it. My guess is `Dim hIcon as long` I'd suggest to add the code to the post instead of pasting an image with the code.

Comment: do you have `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module?

Answer (score 1):

> Compile Error: Variable not defined

means that the variable `hIcon` is not defined.
Write `Dim hIcon as Variant` on the line above the error, to define it.

As it is compiling error, every time before running the code, make sure to go to the VBEditor menu and press **Debug**>**Compile VBA Project** to see whether other errors like this exist:

[image]

Comment: `HIcon as Variant` will work but as written in my comment above my gues it is `Long` (or `LongPtr`)

Comment: @Storax - yes. But for the next undeclared variable, which could be `String` it will not work. This way, `Variant` works a bit like a "silver bullet".

Comment: Usually a handle to an object is a long. I know that you cover with variant every data type but I do not like it if it is not necessary .

Comment: @vityata -Thank you so much for giving such amazing reply. the issue is resolved.

Comment: @Storax - I dislike `Variant` as well, when it is not needed. Silver bullets come with a price the OP has to pay...

Comment: @SRS - you are welcome. Consider reading about data types and declaring the correct one. While `variant` would always work, it is a bit slow, compared to the others. In this case a numeric data type is better - e.g. `Long`.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I'm getting a new error now as **object variable or with block not set** on the same line of code.

Comment: @SRS - probably Image1 or Sheet1 is not present

Comment: Sheet1 is there and image1 is also there. But as I open this file in another system with another excel version it is raising such issue. Is there a solution to fix this. so it will run in any version.